# Is it possible change the way to show push notifications with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app with react native. Recently I add firebase messaging to the project for push notifications. It works perfectly. But I want to show the push notification with image, title, and description in the background (app close or second plane). This is easy to make in the foreground but in background I guess that I need to change some .java files. I don't know do that.

Somebody did it before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, if you are sending push notification from server, firebase also provide options for image, title or descriptions which you can show in a push notification

Comment: Thanks. Maybe do you have an example? Because in my case I sent the push notifications vía my own app cms and when I need make a test via firebase platform with additional fields (image).